# How to capitalize a word I am pulling from the name of the document

Tags: php

I am getting the name of my document like this...

```
<?= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php')?>
```

It is an all lowercase word. How to get the first letter to be capitalized when it appears on my page?

Comment: All your questions seem to be basic reference questions. Please perform basic research before posting here -- that means opening up the PHP manual and looking at the functions documented therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<?= ucfirst(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php'))?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php).

```
$foo = ucfirst(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
ucfirst(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)
Take a look at the comments because Ucfirst does not work right with all languages (Like greek or Turkish)